# Scrollview to scroll table both horizontally and vertically in android

Tags: android

In my android application i am using a table inside a scrollview but am not able to scroll horizontally if the length of content is more.
Could you please let me know any solution for this?

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XML layout:

```
<ScrollView ...>

    <HorizontalScrollView ...>

        YOUR TABLE HERE

    </HorizontalScrollView>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: That's what I just did, but seems it makes horizontal scroll not so smooth. And if I put ScrollView inside HorizontalScrollView, now vertical scroll become not smooth...

Answer (score 0):

Another option is by using GridView

1. Use a horizontal scroll view to contain the GridView
2. Then dynamically re-size the GridView width based on the number of columns that you set for the GridView
3. Lastly, multiply number of columns with the width of each columns

   ```
   GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
   int numberOfColumns = 3;
   int sizeOfWidthPerColumn = 20;
   gridView.setNumColumns(numberOfColumns);
   ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = gridView.getLayoutParams();
   layoutParams.width = convertDpToPixels(numberOfColumns * sizeOfWidthPerColumn, this);
   gridView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
   ```

Now I am able to scroll the GridView horizontally and vertically.